# Divide a container view into 2 controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, containers, master-detail

I need to show a custom tableview in 1 side and the detail in other in ipad like with splitview controller. And so, the detail is visible after a selection of a button on the cell.

My problem comes from the displaying of the detail controller. I sent data from the button in tableview to container controller via a delegate method

```
let containerController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerController") as! ContainerViewController
containerController.reactionViewControllerResponse(selectedMechanism: selectedMechanism)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(containerController, animated: true)
```

and in the container, I create the detail controller via

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    if (selectedMechanism != "" && self.mechanismViewController != nil){
        self.mechanismViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MechanismController") as! MechanismViewController?
        self.mechanismViewController?.selectedMechanism = selectedMechanism

        self.addChildViewController(mechanismViewController!)
        mechanismViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: self.containerView.frame.size.width/2, y: 0, width: self.containerView.frame.size.width/2, height: self.containerView.frame.size.height)
        self.containerView.addSubview((mechanismViewController?.view)!)
        mechanismViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

but due to this line in the tableview controller

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(containerController, animated: true)
```

the detail controller is not shown in the same container controller, but in another one. I tried several things, but either nothing appears or in a different container.

Please help me!!!

P.S.: I don't use splitview controller since I don't need it as inital view controller, and I've already tried and had problems to display only the master on the whole screen, customize the tableview cell....

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, the delegate was badly instantiated.
Thanks to me :)